# Reading Apache error log from PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I want to read the apache2 error log file from PHP (it is currently owned by the www-data user)

Is it safe to change the owner of this file, or to give it less restrictive permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the default configuration is to restrict access to the error log is that it can contain sensitive information regarding either your configuration, or records of warnings/errors that contain usernames, passwords, database connection strings etc.

Allowing the webserver itself (read-only) access to that error log increases the risk for unauthorized access to such information.

But only you can do a risk analysis and judge if the benefits outweigh the risks.

Comment: I know it's raise up security issue.
If I do change permission, what is going to happen with the log rotate ?

Comment: Unless you take specific measures, the log files get re-created after rotating them by reloading the apache server. That results in  them getting default permissions. A `create 0123 username groupname` will create the new log files with specific permissions and owner before running the post rotate script, allowing you to override apache defaults.